# Python cross-platform portable script

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, package

I am working on a web scraper in Pycharm. The project consists of around 5 python files and 8 dependencies. I have a virtual env setup in the IDE. How do I package the files and dependencies so they can be saved on any platform and executed from the command line? I looked into Pyinstaller, but it  looks like Pyinstaller only creates executables for the OS it is running on. So I would need to  create 2 executables for windows and linux. And, I am not necessarily looking for an executable, just need to be able package it so anyone can  download it and run it easily.